# ¿Como anclar o fijar una pestaña en chrome usando javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo la intencion de agregarle a mi sistema "notificaciones" usando el API notificacion que trae javascript.

Como es necesario tener el navegador y la pestaña del sistema abiertos (conectado al sistema), desearia saber como evitar que la persona cierre la pestaña del sistema. Por eso pense en buscar la manera de FIJAR o ANCLAR las pestañas como hace google chrome.

**¿Es posible este funcionamiento desde javascript?**, y por otra parte **¿es posible mostrar las notificaciones en Javascript sin que este la pestaña del sistema abierta?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para tu primera pregunta, si he entendido bien, según la respuesta a una pregunta parecida a la tuya en el foro ingles, si se puede *mediante código* hacer que una pestaña se fije.

```
chrome.tabs.create({
        "url": chrome.extension.getURL("yoururl.html"),
        "pinned": true
    },
    function(tab) {
         tab.highlighted = true;
         tab.active = true;
 });
```

La respuesta esta [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36289244/programatically-pin-a-tab-in-google-chrome).

---

Para tu segunda pregunta, tienes que declarar permisos para que Chrome pueda ejecutar las notificaciones aunque este cerrado es decir, en segundo plano, **dentro de tu `manifest.json`**.

En concreto el permiso `background`.

```
"permissions": [
    "background"
],
```

[Declarar permisos en Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions#background).

**Edit: esto solo funciona cuando se hace en una extensión (donde das permisos), ya que si fuera una simple pagina, seria un grave fallo de seguridad que te dejara fijar las pestañas que quisieras.**

Comment: Excelente probare lo primero y te comento, sobre el permission si estoy usando unicamente javascripts en un entorno con python-flask como puedo declararlo?

Comment: Tu proyecto es una web o una extensión? Si es una web, quizás te puede interesar [Web Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/), en cuanto a tu pregunta sobre python-flask, no estoy muy enterado de eso, lo siento.

Comment: Es una web, ya consegui hacer las notificaciones pero queria prevenir que cerraran la pestaña donde estas conectado.

Comment: No estoy muy seguro, pero creo que no se puede hacer que el usuario no pueda cerrar la pagina, eso seria un problema de seguridad enorme, imagínate las paginas que no te dejan cerrarlas y tienen un minador de criptomonedas, seria un desastre, en cuanto a tu solución, podrías buscar algún tipo de evento antes de cerrar la pagina para preguntar si de verdad quiere cerrarlo ya que no va a recibir notificaciones.

Comment: Me gusta mas tu idea